# Communication between webpage and local speech recognition application

Tags: websocket, local, speech

We are building a webbased information system, but on some of our workstations (let´s say 5%) we need speech recognition available from the webpage. Today we do this with a local winform that is started from the webpage using a local WCF client (that we also use to put the text in the webeditor afterwards), but that is not the best integration ofcourse. I don´t want that winform. I want that the text immediately appears in the website.

Concerning the speech recognition: We have API´s for it, but this is local software. We have to interact with them, because native speech recognition in a webpage is still something that is hard to do, especialy when you have to interact with the speechmike (and buttons) and so on.

Our idea is to do the recognition in a backgroundground application, and send the result to the editor in the webpage. We can run the local application as a local webserver that communicates with the webpage for example.

So my question is: What are the best options to communicate with this local application from a webpage (and vice versa) knowing we have a controlled environment, and we have both control over the (development of the) webpage and the local application. Things I was thinking about, was to use a websocket between the local(host) application and the webpage to transfer the text from the application to the website. Please give me your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

There is HTML5 audio api which allows you to record audio, you can find example here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

You can find several extensions of this implementation, for example

https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

You can send captured audio to server for processing with websockets. If you are running node.js server you can go with socket.io, you can find example here:

https://github.com/cmusphinx/node-pocketsphinx/blob/master/demo/public/index.html

This framework is supported in new browsers, if you want to support old browsers, you can use flash technology, for example see:

https://code.google.com/p/red5/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about communication with speechmikes for example? Thanks again.

Comment: We did some tests with a speechmike (Speechmike III Philips), and the buttons are not recognized as keyboard buttons or mouse buttons... Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: It is not possible to access significant amount of hardware in browser. You might consider to write you own binary browser plugin or choose another technology.